# Is there a significant difference when virtualizing a VPN server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, vpn, openvpn

Basically, my question is this: I have a "server"(a regular PC) with Debian installed. On this machine, I need to have a Tomcat service running at the same time as a VPN server service.

To be more precise, my question is whether there is a significant speed difference for the VPN when it's installed directly on the machine compared to being virtualized on another Debian machine (I also have Tomcat virtualized). My idea was to have each service in a separate virtualization to avoid errors between them and make future migrations easier.

Is it a good idea to do it the way I have, or would you prefer to install everything on the Debian that serves as the server to avoid layers of virtualization?

The server that's virtualizing is a Debian 12. I have virtualized another Debian 12 and an Ubuntu 23.04.

Regards.